# How can I send the (json)values of model to the view conroller?

Tags: swift, api, model-view-controller, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to use the MVC pattern and I used the Alamofire API to get the response as json data. I am not able to send the data to update the tableview from my model.Help me to update my table with the json values.

This is my API:

```
class func showData(completionHandler:(model)->()){
         var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]()
        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (req, res, json) -> Void in
        let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(json.value!)
        if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
            arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
            print(arrRes)
            if  arrRes.count > 0 {
            let name = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"]["name"].stringValue
            let email = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"]["email"].stringValue

                let detail = model(name: name, email: email)
                completionHandler(detail)

            }
            }
        }
}
```

this is my controller:

```
 @IBOutlet var appsTableView: UITableView!
  var tableData:[model] = [model]()


  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.appsTableView.reloadData()
    self.appsTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = appsTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyTestCell") as! newTabelcell
    let dict = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = dict.name
    cell.mailid.text = dict.email
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}

func configureTableView() {
    appsTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    appsTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100.0
    self.appsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

this is my model:

```
  class model: NSObject {
      var name:String!
      var email:String!
   init(name:String , email:String){
      super.init()
      self.name = name
      self.email = email
      }
    }
```

I am having only the tableview and two labels are inserted in the cell;one label for displaying json name and other for displaying json email.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will get some problem because I have worked with this before and I called difference from your call, this is how I use Alamofire:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
            switch responseData.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(value)
                // You can adjust here, because I didn't use Contact Model in my Project.
                if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["contacts"].arrayObject {
                    self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
                }
                if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                    self.tblJSON.reloadData()
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error.description)
            }
        }
```

You can download my project at https://github.com/khuong291/Swift_Example_Series (Project 11). I've finished loading JSON to tableView.

Answer (score 0):

This is my edited API class having the itunessearch method.

```
    func itunesSearch(completionHandler:(songData)->()) {

    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://itunes.apple.com/search?", parameters: ["term" : "tamil new songs", "media" : "music"])
        .responseJSON { (request, response, json) in

                let json = JSON(json.value!)
                if let jsonData = json["results"].arrayObject {
                self.array = jsonData as! [[String : AnyObject]]
                for num  in 1...5{
                let arraydata = json["results"][num]
                    //print([arraydata])
                let artistid = arraydata["artistId"].stringValue
                let trackname = arraydata["trackName"].stringValue

                let song = songData(country: artistid , currency: trackname)   // The parameter name country and currency of this method is just defined in the model class.Don't get confuse by those names which is just reference. 
                completionHandler(song)   }
             }
        }
 }
```

It is exactly working for me..